# Как сделать функцию-фильтр

Tags: python

Есть генератор простых чисел

```
def prime_numbers_generator(n):
    prime_numbers = []
    for number in range(2, n + 1):
        for prime in prime_numbers:
            if not number % prime:
                break
        else:
            prime_numbers.append(number)
            yield number
```

И к нему есть функции, позволяющие проверить числа из генератора на наличие счастливых, и вывести на консоль с пометкой true

```
from operator import eq

def is_eq_sum(str_v, *slices):
    return eq(*map(lambda s: sum(map(int, s)), map(str_v.__getitem__, slices)))


def lucky_digits(v):
    str_v = str(v)
    if len(str_v) < 2:
        return True
    else:

        middle = len(str_v) // 2
        return is_eq_sum(str_v, slice(middle), slice(-middle, None))


for number in prime_numbers_generator(n=1000):
    print(number, lucky_digits(number), sep=' ')
```

Подскажите, как можно упростить этот код и сделать функцию фильтр, которая выдает такой же результат как и сейчас, берет из генератора значения и если число счастливое то рядом пишет true, если нет - false

Comment: А что значит *счастливое* число?

Comment: когда сумма первых цифр равна сумме последних
Если число имеет нечетное число цифр (например 727 или 92083),
727 -> 7(2)7 -> 7 == 7 
92083 -> 92(0)83 -> 9+2 == 8+3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну как-то так:

```py
def prime_numbers_generator(n):
    prime_numbers = []
    for number in range(2, n + 1):
        for prime in prime_numbers:
            if not number % prime:
                break
        else:
            prime_numbers.append(number)
            yield number


def is_lucky(number):
    number = str(number)
    middle = len(number) // 2
    return True if sum(map(int, number[:middle])) == sum(map(int, number[-middle:])) else False


for i in prime_numbers_generator(1000):
    print(i, is_lucky(i), sep=' ')
```

Comment: Проверьте свой код - он сбоит на числах до 10

Comment: @SergBocharov А что, числа до 10 разве не счастливые?

Comment: Да и к тому же у автора вопроса код тоже на числах до 10 выдает `True`...

Comment: Хороший вопрос, не уточнено )